# SQL Server Free Text Search with multiple search words inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, full-text-search

I am trying to do a free text search. basically the search string is being sent to a stored procedure where it executes the free text search and returns the result.

If I search for `red flag`, I want to return the results that matches both red and flag text.

Below is the query I use to return the results.

```
select * from customer where FREETEXT (*, '"RED" and "flag"')
```

This doesn't give me the desired result. Instead this one give the desired result.

```
select * from customer where FREETEXT (*, 'RED') AND FREETEXT (, 'FLAG')
```

My problem is since it's inside a stored procedure, I will not be able to create the second query where clause. I thought both query should return the same result. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [CONTAINS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) instead of [FREETEXT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx):

`select * from customer where CONTAINS(*, '"RED" and "flag"')`

CONTAINS supports boolean syntax. FREETEXT does not -- it is more of a natural language type of search.